Altium Designer Active BOM not showing Manual Solution entry in Excel
I'm using the Altium Designer 24 Licence version. While generating BOM using Active BOM in not get data of Manual Solution created by me in the Excel file.
I'm not getting price of first 3 component price in BOM which I have created manual entry solution
Anyone has faced a similar issue or has any solution will be helpful to me
Thanks


This link will take you, even without a valid license, to an excellent (and official) Altium forum: https://forum.live.altium.com (where all you need to do is register for an account).

Are you sure your Excel template is using the correct column names?

Yes excel template is correct because Im getting other value perfect
